# How to apply functions over a list of list of dataframes?

Tags: r, dplyr

I've got a list `state-list` which contains 4 lists `wa`, `tex`, `cin` and `ohi`, all of which contain around 60 dataframes. I want to apply the same functions to these dataframes. For example, I want to add a new column with a mean, like this:

```
 library(dplyr)

 df # example df from one of the lists 
 
 df %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(mean_value = mean(value))
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a nested `map` to loop over the `list`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
out <- map(state_list, ~ map(.x, ~ .x %>%
                        group_by(x) %>%
                        mutate(mean_value = mean(value)))
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
out <- lapply(state_list, function(lst1) lapply(lst1, 
          function(dat) transform(dat, mean_value = ave(value, x))))
```

Comment: Thank you! One more question - if I were to have a non-piped function (e.g. `df<-as.data.frame(df)` how could I apply it in your code?

Comment: @fifigoblin Did you meant the `base R`.  I updated the post

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful! But what I meant is, if I want to use your `map` code for a non-piped (non-dplyr) function such as transforming each df to data.frame as above, how do I do this?

Comment: In that case, perhaps `map(state_list, ~ map(.x,  ~ transform(.x, mean_value = ave(value, x))))`